# Parse Server isn't listening on port 1337

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 Instance running Ubuntu. 

I've installed on it a Parse Server from github, using these commands:

```
$ npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
$ mongodb-runner start
$ parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY
```

When I started the server, I got this output:

```
appId: APPLICATION_ID
masterKey: ***REDACTED***
port: 1337
mountPath: /parse
maxUploadSize: 20mb
serverURL: http://localhost:1337/parse

parse-server running on http://localhost:1337/parse
```

I've opened another terminal, and I've checked what services are listening on my ports using `sudo netstat -plnt`
and this is the results:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      937/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      924/mongod      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      937/sshd
```

As you can see, there is no Parse server running on port 1337.

What can I do in order to solve it? Maybe it something wrong with it's installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access to a Parse Server running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu's localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287799/how-to-access-to-a-parse-server-running-on-aws-ec2-ubuntus-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

I just made it and connected to the server. Apparently it isn't matter if it is listening or isn't.